# Create data type with types from imported modules

Tags: haskell

Let say we have a module A and a module B where type A and B are declared. 
In a module Super we want to say that Type Super is either A or B like in the following code :

```
-- module A
data A = A String

-- module B
data B = B Int

-- module Super
data Super = A.A
           | B.B
```

but this does not work as we cannot use full qualified data Type in the data constructor (the error is: "Qualified name in binding position") and if we do not put full qualified name like below, type A and B are not whose from module A and B

```
-- module Super
data Super = A
           | B
```

As far my solution is to do like this

```
-- module Super
data Super = A A.A
           | B B.B
```

Is there a better way to achieve this ? I am not sure if I have to use type class

P.s: 
My goal is to have a list of type Super

```
let mySuperList = [ B, A ] :: [Super]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
let mySuperList = [ Left B, Right A ] :: [Either B A]
```

If you can get away without undue multiplication of names, you'll probably find it more powerful in the long run.

Comment: I cannot do that, more types will come

Comment: @Erèbe Then define your own type `data Union = A A.A | B B.B | C C.C | D D.D | ...` and expand it as needed.  This is a lot more usable than nesting `Eithers`, i.e. `Either A (Either B (Either C D))`.  You might also want to check out the [Data types a la carte](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~W.Swierstra/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf) paper that covers how to solve this problem with N types, although keep in mind that there is some significant theory and computational overhead to this method.